# Need help with finding the correct region for this double integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The region is |x+2y| =< 3 and |x-y| =< 3

I tried graphing |x+2y| = 3 and |x-y| = 3 on geogebra and I got the rectangle below but  I am not sure if the region is just the rectangle encompossed by the lines because I inputted '=' and not '=<' to geogebra. In other words, I dont really get what the '=<' really does here. Thank you. In case someone is interested the integral looks like this

$\iint_V xy \,dx\,dy$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $3u = x + 2y$ so that $|u| \leq 1$ and $3v = x-y$ so that $|v| \leq 1$. Then solving these for $x$ and $y$ give
$$r(x,y) = (u + 2 v, u - v)$$
So the integral is
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 (u+2v)(u-v) |r_u\times r_v|\,du\,dv \\
= 3\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 (u+2v)(u-v)\,du\,dv \\
= -4$$
Note that for this region, finding a transformation is really unnecesary. You could do a simple dose of breaking it into smaller regions and integrating like so:
$$2 \int\limits_{-1}^{3}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{3-x}{2}} x y\, dy\, dx + 2 \int\limits_{-3}^{-1}\int\limits_{0}^{x + 3} x y\, dy\, dx = -4$$

Answer (score 2):

Your region is the inner parallelogram.

[image]

(You can see this clearly if you break each of the two conditions into two separate inequalities.)

Btw when evaluating this integral you might want to try a change of variables to make this a square so it’s easier to evaluate with just one integral instead of 2 separate ones.

Edit: Use the following transformation to map the region to a rectangle
$$x=u+v,\qquad y=-\frac12 u+v,\qquad |\det(\text{Jacobian matrix})|=\frac32$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you for spending time on this.

Comment: I am actually having a hard time finding a change of variables for this, could you perhaps help? Thank you

Comment: @MariaJohnson aight see what i added to the answer. Check my jacobian tho i just eyed the determinant so im not 100% positive that its right

Answer (score 0):

The integrand $xy$ is symmetric over $V$ in the sense that $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$, which is to say that the integral over $V$ is twice the integral over either half of $V$ above or below the $x$-axis. So the integral over the parallelogram is

$$\begin{align*}
I = \iint_V xy \, dx \, dy &= 2 \int_{-3}^3 \int_0^{\min\left\{x+3,\frac{3-x}2\right\}} xy \, dy \, dx \\[1ex]
&= 2 \int_{-3}^{-1} \int_0^{x+3} xy \, dy \, dx + 2 \int_{-1}^3 \int_0^{\frac{3-x}2} xy \, dy \, dx
\end{align*}$$

or swapping around variables to get one clean integral,

$$I = 2 \int_0^2 \int_{y-3}^{3-2y} xy \, dx \, dy$$

---

On the other hand, the boundaries of $V$ conveniently suggest a variable change:

$$|x+2y|\le3 \iff -3 \le x + 2y \le 3 \implies u = x + 2y , \quad u\in[-3,3]\\
|x-y|\le3 \iff -3 \le x - y \le 3 \implies v = x - y ,\quad v\in[-3,3]\\
\implies (x,y) = \frac13 (u+2v,u-v) \\
\implies dA = dx\,dy = \left|\det\begin{bmatrix}1/3&2/3\\1/3&-1/3\\\end{bmatrix}\right|\,du\,dv = \frac13\,du\,dv$$

Then the integral is

$$I = \frac13 \int_{-3}^3 \int_{-3}^3 \frac{u+2v}3 \cdot \frac{u-v}3 \, du \, dv$$

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you!