# Area Calculation with Absolute Value Inequality $|x+2y|+|3x+4y|\le 5$

Tags: calculus, geometry, inequality, area, absolute-value

[image: QQ-20230407200402.png]

I am trying to evaluate the area of a plane region defined by the inequality $|x+2y|+|3x+4y|\le 5$. I have plotted the graph of this inequality using an online tool (see image above), but I am unsure how to proceed with calculating the area.

I am hoping someone can provide me with a method to evaluate the area of this plane region, whether it be through geometric or algebraic techniques. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you divide the figure into two rectangles and a parallelogram by considering lines through $5$ and $-5$ ?

Comment: If you assume it is a parallelogram $ABCD$ and know the coordinates of the vertices, the area is $||\vec{AB}\times\vec{AC}||$.

Comment: Using calculus: the equations for each pair of parallel lines making up the boundary provide a good starting point for change of variables and transforming the region into a rectangle. See an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575779/need-help-with-finding-the-correct-region-for-this-double-integral/4576648#4576648) (following "On the other hand...")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint.

Making $u = x+2y,\ v = 3x+4y$ we have $|u|+|v|\le 5$ and in coordinates $(u,v)$ the area is 50. Introducing the area correction due to the coordinates transformation we have

$$
\left(\matrix{du\\ dv }\right)=\left(\matrix{1 & 2\\ 3 & 4}\right)\left(\matrix{dx\\ dy }\right)
$$

and $\left|\det\left(\matrix{1 & 2\\ 3 & 4}\right)\right| = 2$ hence

$$
\text{area}\left(|x+2y|+|3x+4y|\le 5\right) = \frac{50}{2}=25
$$

Comment: +1 : (also).  This is very sharp.  My only constructive criticism is that I (for one) survived "Calculus Vol 1" (Apostol), and I don't fully understand your answer.  It is plausible that the OP (i.e. original poster) will feel the same.  I don't think that you would be **giving too much away** if you provided a deeper discussion of the generic (valid) steps in computing the area in $~(x,y)~$ units, after you have computed the area in other units, [e.g. $~(u,v)~$ units].

Comment: There is a link which offers a quick way to the base argument used in the answer https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_variables_area_calculation

Answer (score 1):

Compute base $\times$ height.

Length of base is $[-10-(-5)]$ or $[-5-(-10)]$, so
$base=15$.

Length of height is (f.e. at $x=0$) obtained via

$|(0+2y)|+|(0+4y)|=5$
$(0+2y)+(0+4y)=10$ or $y=\frac{5}{3}$, so
$height=\frac{5}{3}$.

The area is then $15\times\frac{5}{3}=\frac{75}{3}=25$.